# Efficiently editing content near the top of a very large file on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I have a db dump file that is over 5 gigs in size and I'm looking to do a quick edit to the create database and use database command. This dump is provided to me.

I've been using `vim` to do this from the command line, but it takes a while to load. I'm able to use `less` to read very quickly. Is there a way to edit the file without having to wait several minutes for the full file to load in vim? This can be a param passed to vim, or different common way to edit files from command line.

I'm looking for a general solution that I can apply to other large files too, so would like a linux command that would allow me to edit the top of the file quickly.

Comment: @Meninx, the other question you suggest specifically states that they don't need to edit the file. This question does need edit.

Comment: Does your edit change the total size of the region edited? If so, is it towards the top or bottom of the file?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, it changes the total size, towards the top of the file.

Comment: Then a full rewrite of all content past what you're editing is unavoidable. POSIX semantics don't have a "insert some extra blocks here" operation, or a "shift everything down by X bytes" operation.

Comment: ...now, if you want to make *opening* the file faster, that's doable (perhaps by using an editor that supports `mmap`). But saving it is necessarily going to be a pain.

Comment: Does your edit increase or reduce the file size?

Comment: Is your file format sensitive to white space or does it support certain kind of comments (I mean - can you add certain content to your file without affecting its semantics)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, do you know of a CLI editor that supports `nmap` that comes installed by default by RHEL or CentOS?

Comment: @Leon, ...ahh -- in the case of the edit making it smaller, you're proposing just adding whitespace or comments? Good call.

Comment: @VenomFangs, I honestly don't know. I suppose I could look into whether emacs can be configured to only mmap what it's editing and operate in-place -- I mean, it can be configured for any number of things -- but it'd be easier just to do some magic with dd to copy out and directly operate on the chunk you care about, and then dd the rest of the source file onto the end when you're done. It'll be a big slow rewrite, but you're doomed to that anyhow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes. And in case of increased file size one can, provided that this is going to be done on a sufficiently new system, [`fallocate`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37884191/6394138) a new block near the location of the edit and then pad the extra bytes with whitespace or comments.

Comment: @Leon, heh -- yay for non-POSIX semantics. That's a great answer, and I think it's unfortunate that the question it's on is closed. Perhaps if the OP there hadn't tagged in a bunch of languages it wasn't topical for, it wouldn't have gotten into audiences that it wasn't interesting to. I've edited the tagging over there and nominated to reopen.

Comment: `ex` (or rather `vim` in `ex` mode) might be useful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I never thought that reopening that question made any sense (perhaps I had a newbie mentality then as well as possibly lacked the required privileges). I added my reopen vote to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat`:

```
cat file_with_create_cmd db_dump > new_dump
```

If you want to use that in a subsequent command instead of writing it to a file, you may use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
process_dump <(cat file_with_create_cmd db_dump)
```

Comment: I was thinking about this approach too, was thinking would need a `split` then edit, then concat, but haven't looked into how much time the split time would take. Is this what you are thinking too? Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: You just want to add the create commands *on top* of the dump?

Comment: @VenomFangs, `split` is overkill. If you're only modifying content inside the first 1kb, use `dd` to copy out only the first 1kb (trivial!), edit that, and then dd everything *but* the first 1kb on top. That way the only part you're writing more than once is the segment that you're editing (being written first in its initial state, then a second time by your editor after changes have been made).